# Not all cells are shown in a CollectionViewController Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview

I'm currently developing a periodic table and to show the table I'm using a collection view. The periodic table has 118 elements and I'm trying to show them all in the same page but when I run the app on the simulator, only 77 cells are shown. 
[image: app screen]

Here's the code I used in my Swift file: [source code](https://gist.github.com/nicolocandiani/beee5f2655d9e1fdfde29fb34d574f82)

I was wondering how can I show all the cells on the same screen. I searched online but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: i saw your code... i request you please dont do it like that..

Comment: Why you have set frames for cell?

Comment: try refer https://github.com/robertmryan/PeriodicTable/tree/master/PeriodicTable

Answer (score 0):

steps:
 1. first count the number of items or element in your periodic table, i.e divide the whole frame in to grids, to see how many small square boxes are there..

2. now create a modal for your elements, say for first item Hydrogen, it goes in [Datamodel] array 0 index, and for next 16 array element its empty object as there is no element.. in this way create your modal
3. now create your collectionview cells and populate the data with your modal, where the data are blank object show black image, and for those where there is an element, show respectively
4. now for the size of each element, there is a UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout method

   ```
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

       let width = self.collectionview.frame.size.width/18 as there are 18 columns
       return CGSize(width: width, height: width)

   }
   ```

this way all your cells will be visible in horizontal view.. but then again all cell might not be visible in landscape mode, like elements with 58, 59

so for height of each element you need to do

```
let height = height/9 as there are 9 rows
```

but this way, you. might not get square cells